# Fetch total Memory of Android Device

Tags: java, android, memory, internal-storage

I am trying to fetch the total memory of the Android device. But it returns me as 24GB. However, The total internal memory of the device is 32GB.

I tried using ...

```
public long getInternalFreeSpace()    {
    //Get free Bytes...
    long bytesAvailable = stat.getBlockSizeLong() * stat.getAvailableBlocksLong();
    return bytesAvailable;
}
```

Comment: What is `stat`?  And are you talking about memory, or internal storage?

Comment: I suppose the other 8 Gb are reserver for the system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
public static long getAvailableInternalMemorySize() {
    File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
    long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
    long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocks();
    long size = availableBlocks * blockSize;
    long availableBlocksInKB = size /= 1024;
    long availableBlocksInMB = availableBlocksInKB /= 1024;
    return availableBlocksInMB;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public long getInternalFreeSpace(){
StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
return long bytesAvailable = (long)stat.getBlockSize() *(long)stat.getBlockCount();
}
```

Comment: Erm ... internal != external.  Something seems wrong here

Answer (score 0):

Read **[StatFs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html)** .

> Retrieve overall information about the space on a filesystem

```
private static long getInternalMemorySize() 
 {
    final File pathOBJ = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    final StatFs stat = new StatFs(pathOBJ.getPath());
    final long blockSize;
    final long totalBlocks;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) 
    {
        blockSize = stat.getBlockSizeLong();
        totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCountLong();
    } else 
    {

        blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
        totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCount();
    }
    return totalBlocks * blockSize;
 }
```

You can check **[Get total memory of certain device](https://github.com/NetEase/Emmagee/blob/master/src/com/netease/qa/emmagee/utils/MemoryInfo.java)** .

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it works for you..

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
long bytesAvailable = (long)stat.getBlockSize() *(long)stat.getBlockCount();
long megAvailable = bytesAvailable / 1048576;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stat.getBlockSizeLong() * stat.getFreeBlocksLong();
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html#getFreeBlocksLong()